# Read and Write object on a socket java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

i'm trying to write and read an object between a client and a server, but when i receive the object in the output of the client i receive server.Coordinates, and then the server crash.

With the debug i found that this function doesen't work, but the class of coordinates is the same :

```
void readCoordinates() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //creazione e ricezione oggetto coordinate 
            Coordinates coordinates = (Coordinates) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println("" + coordinates.getX() + " - " + coordinates.getY());
}
```

This is the server :

```
    public class Server {

      static Server server;

      //socket server
      ServerSocket serverSocket;

      //stream output
      OutputStream outputStream; 
      ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
      //stream input
      InputStream inputStream ;
      ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

      public static void main (String[] args) { 

        //Server start
        server = new Server(); 
        server.start(); 
      } 

      public void start(){ 
        try {
            //creazione server socket
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080); 
            System.out.println("ServerSocket awaiting connections...");

            //accept connection
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection from " + socket + "!");

            //output
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

            //input
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

            //receive coordinates
            readCoordinates();

            //write coordinates 
            writeCoordinates(1, 1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error");

            System.exit(1);
        }
      } 

      void readCoordinates() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //creazione e ricezione oggetto coordinate 
            Coordinates coordinates = (Coordinates) objectInputStream.readObject();
            System.out.println("" + coordinates.getX() + " - " + coordinates.getY());
      }

      public void writeCoordinates(int x, int y) throws IOException{
        //creazione e invio oggetto coordinate 
        Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(x, y);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(coordinates);
      }
    }
```

This is the client :

```
public class ConnectionManager {

  //server
  String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";                  
  int serverPort = 8080;

  Socket socket;      
  // stream output
  OutputStream outputStream; 
  ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
  // stream input
  InputStream inputStream;
  ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

  public ConnectionManager() {
    try { 
        //creation socket  
        System.out.println("Socket creation...");
        this.socket = new Socket(serverIP,serverPort);

        //creation input e output stream
        System.out.println("Creation input and output stream...");
        this.inputStream = this.socket.getInputStream();
        this.objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(this.inputStream);
        this.outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        this.objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(this.outputStream);


    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        System.err.println("Unreacheable host"); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Error");

        System.exit(1);
    }
  }

  public void writeCoordinates(int x, int y) throws IOException{
    //send coordinates
    Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates(x, y);
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(coordinates);
  }

  void readCoordinates() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    //read coordinates
    Coordinates coordinates = (Coordinates) objectInputStream.readObject();
    System.out.println("" + coordinates.getX() + " - " + coordinates.getY());
  }
}
```

The class "Coordinates" is the same :

```
public class Coordinates implements Serializable{

  //coordinate
  int x;
  int y;

  Coordinates(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

Where i'm going wrong? I can't write from the server to the client too.

Have a nice day

Comment: Please show the exact output from the server.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice
`ServerSocket awaiting connections...

Connection from Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=61595,localport=8080]!
client.Coordinates

Error

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
`

I find that in the server when i reach the line of **objectInputStream**, the variable is empty and the server crash, but on the client  **objectInputStream** works

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i'm now debugging, and i found that the problem is on the instruction that read the object from the socket

Comment: And what was the coordinate that caused the problem?

Comment: @NomadMaker i tried many combination, but the reading function has never worked.I think the problem is in the cast or in the class, because where i write an object on the socket, the client doesn't stop. Only when the function is called the client or sever crash.

Comment: I've never used an ObjectStream, but I kep hearing that many people have problems with them. I would just use a Reader and Writer, and send text back and forth, with the server and client responsible for creating the objects that are passed.

Comment: @NomadMaker i'll try a couple of hours to resolve this. If this method still doesn't work, i'm going to use Reader and Writer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
For pass an object with a socket, the `class` and the `package` needs to be the same, and then you need to set the same `serialVersionUID`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your client program ends after send coords to server. Server after recive cords try to send another to client but client already close connecttion.

Server code:

```
Server server = new Server();
server.start();
```

And client code:

```
ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
connectionManager.writeCoordinates(5,5);
connectionManager.readCoordinates();
```

I add 1 line `connectionManager.readCoordinates();` after sending cord to server. This line wait for response and not closing connection immediately after sending cords to server.